# What is a "div tag"? (Please explain with examples)

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Okay so,

This might not be the best question but I am new to programming (I'm 12) 
I think I've pretty much gotten down HTML and CSS, and I've moved into JavaScript.
But I do not understand "div tags" and what they do. Can you please explain this to me? :) Thanks

Comment: well that means your still on HTML :) but bravo to you for picking up coding

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The HTML `<div>` element (or HTML Document Division Element) is the generic container for flow content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang. It should be used only when no other semantic element (such as `<article>` or `<nav>`) is appropriate.

**Example**

```
<div>
  <p>Any kind of content here. Such as &lt;p&gt;, &lt;table&gt;. You name it!</p>
</div>
```

**Result**

Any kind of content here. Such as <p>, <table>. You name it!

[DIV - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

As for javascript, its an HTML element and it can be manipulated the same way any other html element can with the except of form elements. [HTMLElement - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

With each HTML element you have browser default styling, like `<b>` and `<strong>` tags their default styling is to bold text or `font-weight: bold`. And `<div>` default styling is `display: block` which just means there is a line break before and after each div element, and of course you know you can change the default styling of that element with CSS

Example on how to change the default styling. this will change every `<div>` element's text color to red

```
 div {
  // change default styling here
  color: red;
 }
```

Looks like you'll need some CSS references too, don't use w3school btw. try MDN [Learn CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css)

Comment: Okay thanks, but so you could do this right?: <div> <b> Hi </b> </div> and the <div> works just like a <p> kinda...

Comment: do what ? change the default styling ?

Comment: Yea change the default styling

Comment: yes you can put anything inside of a div element, and i would change that statement to, a `<p>` works like a `<div>`.  the real difference in html tags is the default styling and how web crawlers interpret the content inside the tag. like h1 is more important or significant than a h6 tag

Comment: Oh, I use W3schools.com, I thought it was good but apparently it does not give many references. I'll try MDN! Thanks!

Comment: I figured. but glad i could help you out.

Answer (score 4):

A `div` tag is the HTML code to specify a `div` element. Example:

```
<div>content</div>
```

The reason that it may be hard to grasp what a `div` element does, is because it does as little as possible. The name div stands for division, and it's just a container that can be used to put text or other elements in. You can of course add styling to a `div` element, like a border and background, but the element still just "looks", is has no special functions like for example an `input` element. You can also add events like a click handler to it, like most elements, but it doesn't react to any events by default.

There are two minimalistic elements like this, the `div` element and the `span` element. The `div` element is a block element, and the `span` element is an inline element. If you add them to the markup without styling them in any way, the `div` element is only visible by how it affects other elements by being a block element, and the `span` element isn't visible at all.

HTML5 adds a few more elements, like `header`, `footer` and `section`, that are similar to the `div` element, just with a more specific purpose to them.

Although a `div` element may seem pretty useless at first, it's actually used quite a lot. Because of its neutral default settings, it's very useful when used with styles and events as it can take any form and function.