# Difference between DIV and BR

Tags: html, tags

Trying to understand the fundamental difference between `<div></div>` and `<br>`. I understand that they both can break up content, but how do I know which one to use and when? Also, is div's main purpose to make reading code easier? Like it groups things together?

I tried typing out two separate paragraphs, one using div and one using br, to see how it would look on a webpage. Outcome was the same.

Comment: Have you read [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/)?

Comment: I think this answer provides a neat explanation of divs [What is a "div tag"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621464/13927534). There's also MDN references in the answer you should definitely check out

Comment: _"I tried typing out two separate paragraphs"_ <p>...</p> is meant for this purpose. For two separate paragraphs, use 2 sets of <p>, or put two <p>s in a div. Refrain from typing text in a <div> directly, it can be done, but it's really meant for sectioning, and containing.

Answer (score 1):

The `div` and `br` tags have different purposes and are used in different contexts.

The `div` tag is used to group together related HTML elements and create a block-level container. The main purpose of the `div` tag is to help structure and organize your content.

On the other hand, the `br` tag is used to insert a line break or a newline within a paragraph of text. It does not group elements together or create a container.

In terms of when to use each tag, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you want to group together related elements and create a container for them, then you would use `div`. If you want to add spacing between lines of text, then you would use `br`.

Comment: To be more clear, you use `<br>` to break a line, not create more space which is a function of CSS. The same effect happens but isn't controllable with HTML alone.

Comment: Breaking a line is also making space in a paragraph. It can be understood in different ways.

Comment: That's what I said

Comment: Sorry, didn't read to the end. 

Answer (score -2):

"Using DIV will allow you to specify what the section break is using CSS. You can also easily control any formatting within that section using styling. A BR is just a line break in the text it doesn't have any inherent meaning. The BR cannot be styled."

Source:https://youtu.be/jTS9JDe20mg

Comment: That explanation is really bad and the use of a div does not necessarily have anything to do with CSS

Comment: <br> is HTML for Bold Return which is what is at the end of a line. Used mainly in text documents. this is ASCII char 13 . A <div> tag Divides two blocks. A <p> is a praragrah.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @pierpy - -
<br>: The Line Break element - HTML - MDN Web Docs - Mozilla

mozilla.org
https://developer.mozilla.org › ... › HTML › Elements
12 Apr 2023 — The HTML element produces a line break in text (carriage-return). It is useful for writing a poem or an address, where the division of lines ...

Answer (score -2):

The div tag is a block element and br tag is an inline element.

Div tag will create a group of elements.
BR tag will create a line break.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).